# Where does this come from: "warning NU1803: You are running the 'restore' operation with an 'HTTP' source"

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2022

I'm using QuanTower API (they have a VS plug-in) and when building a C# project I always get:

```
warning NU1803: You are running the 'restore' operation with an 'HTTP' source, 'http://nuget.org'. Non-HTTPS access will be removed in a future version. Consider migrating to an 'HTTPS' source.
```

Their support says they don't see that message.

I have no clue where it is coming from, what it is or what is causing it?   How do I figure out what is causing this message?

TIA!!

Comment: I found it under Options / NuGet Package Manager / Package Sources.  There were two entries, one "Package Source" http://nuget.org, another "nuget.org" https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.   I disabled the first one (uncheck it).  That fixed it, when I went back in there is now a 3rd option of "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" pointing to SDK\NuGetPackages.  Maybe someone could answer about what all this means / is.   I don't know anything about NuGet and it says no packages installed when managing packages for solution.

Comment: Error codes that start with an `NU` prefix are from NuGet. The warning is that the configured URL should be changed to use 'https'.

Comment: You can delete the `http://nuget.org` entry.

Comment: NuGet is a package manager. When a project is built there is a 'restore' operation which checks for and either retrieves or updates packages. I'm not sure why restore is running with no packages.

Comment: @user3161924 I posted an answer, you can take a look. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue you encountered:

[image]

This is only a warning which start from Nuget 6.3 which let you know that you’re using a non-HTTPS source..

You can take a look at this announcement:

[HTTPS everywhere](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/https-everywhere/)

The actual problem on your side is the source you were using. The nuget gallery website url can't be the source of the nuget.

You may need some concepts of these knowledge:

***1, Nuget Tool***

Nuget is a free and open-source package manager for the Microsoft development platform. Nuget source is a concept under this tool.

***[An introduction to NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget)***

***2, Nuget Gallery***

This is a website, you can search the packages maded by official of personal.

***https://www.nuget.org/:***

This is the main website for the NuGet project. Here, you can search for packages, publish new packages, and read documentation on how to use NuGet, among other things. You can also download the NuGet client tools from this website.

**3, Nuget V3 entry point**

***https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json:***

This URL is the entry point for the NuGet V3 API. It's not intended to be used with a web browser. Instead, it's designed for use by the NuGet client tools (like nuget.exe or the NuGet features in Visual Studio) when they need to interact with a NuGet repository. This URL provides a JSON response that includes the URLs of other services in the NuGet V3 API, like search, package metadata, and package download services.

You can also refer to this official document:

[sources command (NuGet CLI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-sources)

You can see that it mentioned:

> Note that the source URL for nuget.org is
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

You can use this entry point for restore mostly public nuget packages via nuget tool, you can use one source which use this as the upstream. Or use a source which you make sure contains the packages you need.

So, nuget is a tool which extensively used within the .NET ecosystem to manage libraries and tools. [www.nuget.org](http://www.nuget.org) is a user-facing website, while api.nuget.org/v3/index.json is a service-facing API endpoint.

For the 'http://nuget.org' link you use, it even not the standard format of nuget gallery. Why you enter this and finally go to the nuget gallery is because the server configuration, When you enter a URL without the `www` subdomain, the server is configured to redirect you to the `www` version of the site.